# Google Firebase Analytics - How to notify the user of data collection on iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, app-store, firebase-analytics, privacy

How should I notify users of my iOS app of the default data collection done by Google's Firebase Analytics?

I recently made an iOS application and released it to the app store. To gain more insight into how my app is being used, I am looking into updating it to include the Firebase analytics API. The app does not collect any other information other than the default information that Firebase Analytics already collects. [According to Google](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318039?hl=en), this includes:

> Session duration, Operating system, Device models, Geography ...

Even though it does not collect any sensitive user information (eg, username, email...), according to the [Firebase User Policy](https://firebase.google.com/policies/analytics/) apparently I still must notify the user of data collection:

> You are required to notify your App Users by disclosing the following information:
>
> - The Google Analytics for Firebase features you have implemented.
> - How App Users can opt-out of the Google Analytics for Firebase features you use, including through applicable device settings, such as the device advertising settings for mobile apps, or any other available means

Should I paste a disclosure itself in a menu on the settings page or just a link to it? And am I even understanding this correctly - do I even need to notify the user of this data collection by the Google Firebase Analytics platform?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're required to notify and inform users how they can opt-out.

Useful example from Aurora Forecast iOS app:

[image]